# Initializing superclass in derived class's constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, derived-class

**MemRef** is a simple class to point to some memory it doesn't own.

Base class:

```
class MemRef {

protected:
    const char *               _ptr;
    std::size_t                _len;

public:
    // Constructors
    MemRef()                        : _ptr(0), _len(0) {}
    MemRef(const string& s)         : _ptr(s.c_str()), _len(s.length()) {}
    MemRef(const char* b, size_t l) : _ptr(b), _len(l) {}
};
```

**Loaded_MemRef** is a subclass that supplies its own buffer, when the caller can't be trusted to supply memory that remains allocated and unchanged for the lifetime of the **MemRef**.  **Loaded_MemRef** copies the data into a secret buffer it controls, and then points to it, allowing me to treat it like a plain **MemRef**.

Derived class:

```
class Loaded_MemRef : public MemRef {

private:
    const string _memory;

public:
    Loaded_MemRef(const string& s) : ??? {}
    Loaded_MemRef(const char*);
    Loaded_MemRef(const char*, const size_t);
};
```

I'm having trouble creating the ctors for **Loaded_MemRef**.  I must copy into **_memory** the memory the caller provided *first*, before calling **MemRef**'s ctor; otherwise **MemRef** can't retrieve a valid **_memory.c_str()**.  But my understanding is that the call to **MemRef(_memory)** must come first, before I initialize **Loaded_MemRef**'s members.  So I tried this:

```
Loaded_MemRef(const string& str) :
    MemRef(),            // get this over with
    _memory(str),                  // copy str into _memory
    MemRef::_ptr(_memory.c_str()), // (LINE 108) "reach up into" MemRef and set its protected members
    MemRef::_len(_memory.length())
{}
```

This complains:

```
MemRef.cpp: In constructor 'Loaded_MemRef::Loaded_MemRef(const std::string&)':
MemRef.cpp:108: error: expected class-name before '(' token
MemRef.cpp:108: error: expected '{' before '(' token
```

(Line 108 is indicated above; the next line, setting **_len**, doesn't get flagged, although perhaps the compiler bailed.)

What is the *right* way to do this?

Comment: Why does `Loaded_MemRef` such weird constructors?

Comment: @KerrekSB: one's for a string ref, one's for a null-terminated c-string, and one's for a buffer (no null termination, needs length).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to set stuff in the initializers. You can do it in the body of the constructor:

```
Loaded_MemRef(const string& str) :
    MemRef(),            // get this over with
    _memory(str),        // copy str into _memory
{
    _ptr = _memory.c_str();
    _len = _memory.length();
}
```

If your base class had `const size_t _len`, it would be impossible to implement what you want, because `const` members require initializers, and initialization order mandated by C++ is opposite to what you need.

Comment: Does what you said about **const _len** also apply to **const _ptr**?

Comment: Yes; but your `_ptr` is not *that* kind of `const` (it is not problematic) - the problematic one would be `const char *const _ptr`

Answer (score 2):

You could just change `_ptr` and `_len` from the body of the `Loaded_MemRef` constructor (since they're `protected`).

You could give `MemRef` a (`protected`?) member function for changing where it points, and use that from the body of the `Loaded_MemRef` constructor.

Or if you really, really want/need to initialize the `MemRef` just once, you can move that `string` to the one thing that does get initialized before a base class: another base class (declared either `virtual` or earlier).

Using only C++03:

```
struct Loaded_MemRef__Base
{
    std::string _memory;
    explicit Loaded_MemRef__Base(const std::string& str)
      : _memory(str) {}
};

class Loaded_MemRef
    : private Loaded_MemRef__Base,
      public MemRef
{
public:
    Loaded_MemRef(const string& str) :
        Loaded_MemRef__Base( str ),
        MemRef( _memory.data(), _memory.length() )
    {}
};
```

With C++11 features:

```
struct Loaded_MemRef__Base
{
    std::string _memory;
};

class Loaded_MemRef
    : private Loaded_MemRef__Base,
      public MemRef
{
public:
    Loaded_MemRef(std::string str) :
        Loaded_MemRef__Base{ std::move(str) },
        MemRef( _memory.data(), _memory.length() )
    {}
};
```

Comment: Nice example of using C++11's std::move().  I'm unclear whether your braces there are required, or could parens be used equally well?

Comment: The braces are needed since the C++11 example doesn't define a constructor for the `struct`.  Parentheses say "call a constructor with these arguments"; braces say "initialize the members of a struct (or a std::initializer_list) with these values".

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize the members of the superclass in the derived class initialization list, even if they are protected. The solution is to use a constructor of the superclass.